# How many berries can I feed to a Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was next to a friendly gym and, since it was being attacked, it was preventing me from adding my Pokémon to help defend it. As I am able to feed other trainer's Pokémon berries, I feed it a few berries to boost it's motivation as my contribution.

After a little bit, I received a message saying something along the lines of "*Gyarados seems happy, try feeding berries to another Pokémon*".

How many berries am I allowed to feed a Pokémon before I can't feed it anymore?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be to max motivation? (Also attack*ed* not being attack)

Comment: @n_palum It wasn't at max motivation, roughly 1/2 when I got the message

Comment: Hmph weird. Guess someone's gotta test then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6iw54x/limit_of_berries_you_can_feed_is_10_someone_if/), you can only feed a Pokémon **10** berries before it is full. The amount of motivation a Pokémon has does not affect this.

> Limit of berries you can feed is 10! (Someone is currently fighting my gym and I kept forcing Dragonite to more...)
>
> [image: dragonite is full]

Comment: That 9% battery life is killing me, but Pokemon Go will do that...

Comment: @TBear yeah, Vemonus' phone must have a huge battery!

Comment: @DoktorJ that wasn't my battery, haha, but I *do* use a battery case.