# What is the cooldown time for feeding berries to ally Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

As indicated in the question [How many berries can I feed to a Pokémon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311738/how-many-berries-can-i-feed-to-a-pok%C3%A9mon),
I am aware that after feeding 10 berries to an ally Pokémon,
it becomes "full".

How long do I have to wait before the Pokémon becomes "hungry" again
so that I can feed it more berries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [Silph Road Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6n0i3w/a_detailed_look_at_the_berry_feeding_limit/) indicates a 30 minute fixed timer.  The timer starts on the first berry and resets after 30 minutes.  That is, if you feed 5 berries, wait 15 minutes, feed 5 berries, wait 15 minutes, the timer resets and you may feed 10 berries immediately.

There is another restriction on feeding up to 10 pokemon within a 30 minute rolling window.